# how KEA algorithm for kea phrase extraction use WEKA to find keyphrases

Tags: weka

How KEA algorithm for kea phrase extraction use WEKA to find keyphrases from given text documents. I have understood the basic logic i.e., it first cleans the input and then generate n gram and remove stop words and does stemming. Generate feature value. I wan't to know what does KEA do next? For what purpose does it use WEKA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KEA is based on machine learned model using supervised learning techniques. Basically what this means is we first need to get training data. This training data has example documents and list of key phrases selected by humans. You use this training data to calculate features and then you feed this features to machine learning algorithm which builds model. The model essentially tells you what should be the output if input is given set of features. One of the best resource to go more deeper in machine learning works is [book from creators of WEKA themselves](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123748569).

KEA uses Naive Bayes algorithm to calculate output from given set of features. WEKA has nice efficient implementation of Naive Bayes. But I wouldn't say WEKA is special in that. Nearly any machine learning toolkit worth its salt would have good implementation of Naive Bayes and so you could have used any toolkit really. But that's what happens next. You give these features to Naive Bayes implementation in WEKA and get the output which is ranking scores for key phrases.

Please [see here](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~eibe/pubs/chap_Witten-et-al_Windows.pdf) for how KEA works starting at page 5. Page 6 describes what you have already found, i.e., it does stemming and ngrams. Page 7 and 8 describes the features it calculates. Next pages describes training and ML algo.

Comment: It depends on header you put in arff. In data section, you basically put each training instance in CSV format. More info here: http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~ml/weka/arff.html